# Production rate of parallel reactions

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

> The degradation of hydrogen peroxide in water $\ce{(2 H2O2 (aq) → 2 H2O +O2 (g))}$ can be catalyzed by $\ce{Br-}$ and $\ce{H3O+}$. Derive an expression for the production rate for the following reactions:
>
> $\ce{H2O2 + H3O^+ <-> H3O2+ + H2O}$ , where the reaction constants are $k_1$ and $k_{-1}$
>
> $\ce{H3O2+ +Br- -> HOBr + H2O}$ , where the reaction constant is $k_2$
>
> $\ce{HOBr + H2O2-> O2 + H3O+ + Br-}$, where the reaction constant is $k_3$

I known that $\ce{H3O2+}$ and $\ce{HOBr}$ are intermediates and so I can use the steady-state approximation and set these rates to zero. From this I get that:

$$\frac{d[O_2]}{dt} = \frac{k_1k_2k_3 [\ce{Br-}][\ce{H3O2+}][\ce{H3O+}]}{k_1k_3[\ce{H2O}] + k_2k_3[\ce{Br-}]}$$

Which I hope is correct.

Then they ask:

> Under what conditions does: $$\frac{d[O_2]}{dt} = k [\ce{Br-}][\ce{H3O2+}][\ce{H3O+}]$$

Here I am unsure if the conditions are that we could suppose that $\ce{H2O}$ is in excess and thus not include it in our rate expression, and that $\ce{Br-}$ also can be excluded since it is a spectator ion.

I would appreciate if someone could confirm that my expression for the rate of production is correct and that my conditions are valid. Thank you!

Comment: "are intermediates and so I can use the steady-state approximation and set these rates to zero" Which rates? For intermediate $\ce{I}$, the steady state approximation says that because $\ce{[I]}$ is small, then change in its concentration is also small: $\frac{d}{dt}\ce{[I}] = 0$. I hope that's what you are doing when you are try to "set these rates to zero."

Comment: The following must be true  $$k_1k_3[\ce{H2O}] \gg k_2k_3[\ce{Br-}]$$, then you can neglect the influence of  $\ce{[Br-]}$ on the value of the denominator. Another option is excluding $\ce{H2O}$ from the $k_{-1}$ reaction

Comment: You still have an intermediate in you equation for oxygen production so this cannot be correct yet.

Comment: As both $\ce{[H_2O}$ and $\ce{[Br^-]}$ are not consumed, their concentration do not change during the whole process. So there is no conditions for the last equation to be applied, namely : $$\ce{d[O_2]/dt = k [Br^-][H_3O_2^+][H_3O^+]}$$ This expression is valid at all times.